# Filter nodes that have a field date that is not in the future

Tags: 8, views, datetime

I have a view setup to list nodes that have "public date" date field that are in the past.

To do that, the filter is doing a Content: Field Public Date <= today.

"today" if the site is set to UTC timezone, in views that comes out as:

```
DATE_FORMAT('2020-12-10T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Except that means here in EST, nodes would be listed 5 hours earlier than intended.

If I set the site timezone to America/New_York (which it should be), then "today" in the views query comes out as:

```
DATE_FORMAT('2020-12-09T19:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Except that (as of this writing) would be yesterday at 7 PM EST.

What we want is for nodes to not be in the listing until their public date is met in EST. So if a node has a public date of tomorrow (December 11th 2020) and today is December 10th 2020, then that node should not be listed until December 11th, midnight.

I don't work with date fields as filters like this often, is this the way to typically do it? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: AFAIK Drupal is well versed in time zones so there should be no problems if you set it up correctly. I guess it makes the most sense to set your website time zone to EST, if that's what you use the most, and also edit your Views Filter settings and set it to EST time zones. This way you don't get confusing results. Are you seeing a bug where Drupal doesn't output time zone times correctly?

Comment: [I'm also seeing the same thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1GBV.png), looks like you discovered a bug. The issue occurs with other time zones too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a core bug. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2647292

Comment: Yes, it does seem that this is indeed a core bug. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1182256